# Official Codelite has Viruses?

Tags: c++, g++, antivirus, virus, codelite

I am a first time user of stack overflow, and a newbie programmer. I was looking for a free IDE and I came across Codelite. I downloaded it and ran it, but Kaspersky flagged codelite-terminal.exe and two programs in the program setup file as viruses. I downloaded it from the official source forge website. Please advise. Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Did you use this link: http://downloads.codelite.org/

Comment: You can get VS for free now--for the last few years in fact--in the form of VS "Community".  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx

Comment: Yes Mert, I used that link

Comment: It does not contain any viruses.

Answer (score 1):

It does not contain any viruses. You can always download the code and search for them ;) - thats the beauty of open source

Don't believe everything Kaspersky  tells you...

*Eran Ifrah*

*Author of CodeLite IDE*

Comment: FYI, My corporate Symantec scanner also flagged codelite-cc.  I don't believe codelite contains any virus.  But once it's flagged, I can't use it on a work computer anymore.